# How can I reference a script that is in my pages directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to keep a good practice of keeping context together and in that regard, I like how Razor Pages forces you to place your view models next to its view. I'd like to do this with script files as well.

For example, if script is a bit large and is only used on this particular page, it may not be the cleanest thing to have it in a render section in the cshtml. Instead, I'd want to place it into its own .js file. But to keep the project easy to navigate for team members, I'd like to place that .js file in the same folder next to its view and view model. I'm not sure how to link that file, or if I even can. If I give `src` a path to the file, it is not found. Assuming that's because wwwroot is the only folder setup to host static files.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option to the `StaticFilesProvider` in your `Configure` method:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"Pages")), RequestPath="/Pages"
});
```

See the documentation on Static Files in ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1